# Trying to set Request headers in Win 2003, am told 'Operation is not supported on this platform'

Tags: asp.net, iis

We're running IIS 6.0 on a Windows 2003 server box and are trying to set the accept-language request header in the Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax:

`Request.Headers.Set("accept-language", "en-US")`

We get a message telling us `Operation is not supported on this platform.`

The thing is, this works fine on my local copy of the app-- however I'm running IIS 7 on Windows 7. Would anyone know what might be going on, I know Windows 2003 isn't the latest and greatest but setting some request headers shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: W2K3 (which SP by the way ?) is not only neither latest nor greatest but a hefty security risk ...

Comment: @Marged I know, we're trying to get to Server 2012...it's a legacy box...

Comment: You should turn it off now. See this [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=10394). MS no longer issues security updates to Win2003 at any SP level. You're running a huge risk if this system is on the public internet.